# Merge [playbook] into [blackberry-playbook]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [playbook](/questions/tagged/playbook) and [blackberry-playbook](/questions/tagged/blackberry-playbook) are equivilant. [playbook](/questions/tagged/playbook) should be a synonym instead of its own tag.